# complex number example in c++ not working

Tags: c++, version, complex-numbers

the simple example code from (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) is not working and I don't know why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::complex_literals;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);

    std::complex<double> z1 = 1i * 1i;     // imaginary unit squared
    std::cout << "i * i = " << z1 << '\n';

    std::complex<double> z2 = std::pow(1i, 2); // imaginary unit squared
    std::cout << "pow(i, 2) = " << z2 << '\n';

    double PI = std::acos(-1);
    std::complex<double> z3 = std::exp(1i * PI); // Euler's formula
    std::cout << "exp(i * pi) = " << z3 << '\n';

    std::complex<double> z4 = 1. + 2i, z5 = 1. - 2i; // conjugates
    std::cout << "(1+2i)*(1-2i) = " << z4*z5 << '\n';
}
```

I am compling with

```
c++ -o complex_numbers_example complex_numbers_example.cpp -std=c++11
```

and get the error

```
complex_numbers_example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
complex_numbers_example.cpp:8:26: error: ‘complex_literals’ is not a namespace-name
     using namespace std::complex_literals;
                          ^
complex_numbers_example.cpp:8:42: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
     using namespace std::complex_literals;
                                          ^
complex_numbers_example.cpp:11:31: error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""i’
     std::complex<double> z1 = 1i * 1i;     // imaginary unit squared
                               ^
complex_numbers_example.cpp:11:31: note: use -std=gnu++11 or -fext-numeric-literals to enable more built-in suffixes
complex_numbers_example.cpp:11:36: error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""i’
     std::complex<double> z1 = 1i * 1i;     // imaginary unit squared
                                    ^
complex_numbers_example.cpp:11:36: note: use -std=gnu++11 or -fext-numeric-literals to enable more built-in suffixes
complex_numbers_example.cpp:14:40: error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""i’
     std::complex<double> z2 = std::pow(1i, 2); // imaginary unit squared
                                        ^
complex_numbers_example.cpp:14:40: note: use -std=gnu++11 or -fext-numeric-literals to enable more built-in suffixes
complex_numbers_example.cpp:18:40: error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""i’
     std::complex<double> z3 = std::exp(1i * PI); // Euler's formula
                                        ^
complex_numbers_example.cpp:18:40: note: use -std=gnu++11 or -fext-numeric-literals to enable more built-in suffixes
complex_numbers_example.cpp:21:36: error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""i’
     std::complex<double> z4 = 1. + 2i, z5 = 1. - 2i; // conjugates
                                    ^
complex_numbers_example.cpp:21:36: note: use -std=gnu++11 or -fext-numeric-literals to enable more built-in suffixes
complex_numbers_example.cpp:22:43: error: ‘z5’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout << "(1+2i)*(1-2i) = " << z4*z5 << '\n';
                                           ^
```

When I try to compile with

```
cpp -o complex_numbers_example complex_numbers_example.cpp
```

it works, but when executing I get

```
bash: ./complex_numbers_example: Permission denied
```

For c++ I am using version

```
c++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
```

and for cpp I am using version

```
cpp (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Comment: Requires C++14 live: https://godbolt.org/z/xJyk2e

Comment: @Jan SE - you really did a good job of asking the question: a) you referenced where you got the code from, b) you included a complete, self contained example, c) you posted the specific error(s), d) you gave your compiler version and platform.  PROBLEM: it simply appears that the example isn't compatible with your version of G++ 5.4.

Comment: @paulsm4 Where can I find out which version I need? And is there a difference in c++, gcc, cpp ??? Which one is the best to use? And is it hard to install a new version?

Comment: @JanSE What happens if you use `c++ -o complex_numbers_example complex_numbers_example.cpp -std=c++14`?

Comment: _"Where can I find out which version I need?"_: use the online compiler link (above) and change the compiler version. Change the compiler to earlier versions until you find the compile/not compile boundary.  Answer 4.9.0 and above.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks! it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex literals were added in c++14, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i

You need to compile with:

```
c++ -o complex_numbers_example complex_numbers_example.cpp -std=c++14
```

Don't try to compile with `cpp`, that is the **C** **P**re **P**rocessor and will produce a preprocessed c++ file not an executable.